# Add quick content viewer to 'ReviewTaskStates' and 'ReviewRejectionReasons'

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

In the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), some of the small tables have an (i) button, which upon clicking shows you the contents of that table. This saves you a `SELECT * FROM VoteTypes` if you couldn't remember the ID for upvotes.

[image]

My request it to add this as well for two other tables: ReviewTaskStates and ReviewRejectionReasons. Both are small enough (comparable to the sizes of other tables for which the feature is enabled).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the following [class](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Helpers/HelperTableCache.cs#L192) the default can be changed

```
public class HelperTableCachePreferences
{
    public HelperTableCachePreferences()
    {
        PerSite = false;
        IncludePattern = ".*(Types|TaskStates|RejectionReasons)$";
    }
    /// other code omitted
}
```

but the settings get instantiated by the AppSettings class anyway, which get its values from either appSettings.config file or the AppSettings table found in the DataExplorer database. The setting in the config or the row should look like this:

```
<add key="HelperTableOptions" 
     value="{ PerSite: false, IncludePattern: '.*(Types|TaskStates|RejectionReasons)$' }"/>
```

I tried it locally and it worked for me, YMMV.

Give Nick 6 to 8 weeks to change this.

Comment: This hasn't been changed (even after waiting 6-8 months). Would it make sense to make a PR?

Comment: @Glorfindel I can prep the PR but it still needs Nick to alter the settings table in the db. Only a PR is not going to cut it.

Comment: OK, sad :( ....

Comment: Asked some support from Tim [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39024820#39024820)