# Can the PerSite setting be switched to true so the shown metadata is consistent?

Tags: bug, data-explorer

I was looking at some of the *-Types tables in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer. specially `CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes`.

As I'm lazy I clicked the (i) that is found in the right hand side of the SEDE query editor and to my surprise it listed values up to id = 13 where a `select * from CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes` returned values with id = 16.

[image: missing values]

On closer inspection I believe the current values shown in the meta data are from Software Engineering.SE. I think that is because in the [Data.StackExchange] database [`select top 1 * from Sites`](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/5f043d08e5c3bdfbfdb162267f11f2442795f37f/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Helpers/HelperTableCache.cs#L112)<sup>1</sup> returns *programmers* as the first row. It populates the TablesCache with the values found in that database.

It looks like the Application setting for `PerSite` is false as I also maintain that same value here: [Add quick content viewer to 'ReviewTaskStates' and 'ReviewRejectionReasons'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288838/add-quick-content-viewer-to-reviewtaskstates-and-reviewrejectionreasons/288843#288843)

While it was reasonable to have that value set to false when all *Types* tables were the same across all databases, with the addition of a Types table that does have per site content, the `PerSite` setting has to be reconsidered.

I propose the `PerSite`  setting is switched to `true`. This can be done in the appsettings.config or in the AppSettings table but requires a restart as the value is never rechecked at runtime. Setting the value to `true` will incur a higher memory load as now the values of the  %Types tables of each of the 350 databases has to be kept in memory.

It is a minor issue as only two tables are affected at the moment, CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes and PostNoticeTypes. None of the other *Types tables seem to have per site specific content. If the setting is left as is, consider this report to be the sign-post for future confused users.

---

<sub>1.  that `select top`  isn't stable due to a lacking order by clause, that is maybe another issue that needs fixing</sub>